# Error al crear claves foráneas

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `MeliaDTB`.`hotel`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MeliaDTB`.`hotel` (
          `ID` INT NOT NULL,
          `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `gerente` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `dir_postal` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `ciudad` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `cadena` INT NOT NULL,
          `estrellas` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
          INDEX `fk_hotel_ciudad1_idx` (`ciudad` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_hotel_cadena_hotelera1_idx` (`cadena` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_hotel_ciudad1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`ciudad`)
            REFERENCES `MeliaDTB`.`ciudad` (`nombre`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_hotel_cadena_hotelera1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`cadena`)
            REFERENCES `MeliaDTB`.`cadena_hotelera` (`ID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Relación completa de las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar, me marca error en la tabla `hotel`, pero no veo el problema. Había estado pensando que era por que tomaba valores VARCHAR de otra tabla, pero me ocasiona el mismo problema **1215** si tomo INT (clave primaria)

Comment: Es posible que sea porque `ciudad` no  primary key en su tabla. Estas seguro de que usando `ID` como FK te da el mismo error?

Comment: esque necesito el nombre, no el ID, por eso puse la referencia a nombre(VARCHAR). aun no entiendo cual es el problema.

Comment: entonces debo cambiar todas las referencias varchar por la clave primaria?

Comment: recomendaciones un poco mas especificas de lo que debo hacer, no soy muy experto en bdd.

Comment: Yo es que no suelo trabajar con mysql. Lee [la referencia de mysql sobre foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) para informarte mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Respuesta corta**
Primero tienes que añadir un índice a la columna `nombre` en la tabla `ciudad`:

```
CREATE INDEX nombre_ciudad_idx ON ciudad(nombre);
```

Esto es así porque [InnoDB requiere que la columna o grupo de columnas referenciadas tenga un índice en ellas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) (algo que no es realmente soportado por el estándar SQL, sino que es una extensión de InnoDB).

---

**Respuesta larga**

El error 1215 en MySQL simplemente es "no se puede añadir la clave foránea". Esto se puede deber a diferentes motivos, los más frecuentes que he visto son:

- **Los tipos de datos de la columna clave foránea y la referenciada deben ser los mismos**. Éste suele ser el error más común en este tipo de casos, pero parece que no es en el tuyo.
- **La columna referenciada debe ser un índice único**: en el estándar SQL se indica que las columnas referenciadas deben ser únicas. InnoDB sí permite crear claves foráneas que referencien a campos no únicos, por lo que esto no es tu problema *directamente* (aunque sí está relacionado).
- **Restricciones específicas al motor de base de datos (InnoDB, MyISAM, NDB...) usado**. La implementación que MySQL hace de las claves foráneas/secundarias difiere un poco del estándar SQL y depende un poco del motor que uses:

  - [MyISAM no soporta claves foráneas y su definición es ignorada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (aunque éste no es tu caso porque usas InnoDB).
  - [NDB soportará claves foráneas dependendiendo de la versión usada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-cluster/7.3/en/mysql-cluster-news-7-3-1.html#mysqld-5-6-10-ndb-7-3-1-ndb-fks) (de nuevo, éste no es tu caso porque usas InnoDB).
  - [InnoDB requiere que las columnas referenciadas tengan índices en ellas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) y no permite claves foráneas a tablas que tengan particionamiento definido por el usuario.

Éste último punto es el que te está causando el error casi con toda seguridad. El problema será que no tienes definido ningún índice en la tabla `ciudad` para el campo `nombre`. Entonces la definición de la clave foránea `fk_hotel_ciudad1_idx` fallará (la de `fk_hotel_cadena_hotelera1_idx` funcionará correctamente porque está referenciando a un campo que es clave primaria).

---

Como recomendación, me plantearía cambiar un poco la estructura de tu base de datos y hacer que las claves foráneas apunten a claves primarias o únicas. Aunque luego tengas que hacer joins para obtener el valor del nombre de la ciudad, van a hacer la base de datos más robusta y fácil de mantener (y migrar).

Comment: Workbeanch me genero los index automaticamente, pero asi me sigue marcando.